# Loop through public constants in a static class

Tags: c#, reflection

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4994521/223742) post talks about properties however I am trying to get at the constants in the following static class:

```
public static class SpYtMessageConstants
{
    public const int MSG_NOOP = 1;
    public const int MSG_PING = 2;
}
```

I want to loop through all the constants and get each value values. This is for a unit test to make sure nobody has added the same value twice.

Comment: @HimBromBeere if you look at my original post you will see I reference that exact same post. However it is dealing with properties accessing constants not directly constants as is my case. So it is not a direct answer.

Comment: If you only have read the other answers also and not only the accepted one, you would have got the solution yourself. Anyway here´s another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261824/how-can-i-get-all-constants-of-a-type-by-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want `static` (and `public`) **fields'** (not properties) values which can be set at compile time only (`IsLiteral`) while not being `readonly` - `IsInitOnly`

```
Object[] values = typeof(SpYtMessageConstants)
  .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
  .Where(f => f.IsLiteral && !f.IsInitOnly)
  .Select(f => f.GetValue(null))
  .ToArray();
```

Finally, in your particular case `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` is redundant, however, it can be useful in case classes are *inherited*:

```
public class BaseClass {
  public const int BaseConst = 123;
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
  public const int DerivedConst = 456;
}
```

in case `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` specified *both* `BaseConst` and `DerivedConst` are returned